# Incorrect behavior of inline elements with inline-block elements

Tags: html, css, web, inline

Now, the difference between inline and inline-block elements is that inline element does not allow for margin-top or margin-bottom as compared to inline-block elements. However, in the below example, whenever I apply a margin to the inline-block element, a margin appears for the inline ones too. Can anyone tell me why? I have spent over an hour trying to figure out but failed.

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        div {
            background:yellow;
            margin:10px;
            height:70px;
        }

        a {
            display:inline;
            background-color:#FFF;
            width:20px;
            height:20px;
            border:solid black 1px;
        }

        span {
          margin-top:10px;
          display:inline-block;
          background:red;
        }
        a, span{
         vertical-align:center;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<a>abcd</a>
<a>efgh</a>
<span>Some text</span>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

What i got is this.[image]

Here both the abcd and efgh  elements have the same 10px margin as the span.

Answer (score 1):

> Now, the difference between inline and inline-block elements is that inline element does not allow for margin-top or margin-bottom as compared to inline-block elements.

*One* difference is that margin-top and margin-bottom have *no effect* on inline elements. It's not the only difference. Inline elements still have the margin *values* specified on them.

> Here both the abcd and efgh elements have the same 10px margin as the span.

No they don't. The abcd and efgh elements have 0 margins on them. But they are *vertically aligned* with the span element through their respective baselines. That's why the abcd and efgh elements are moved vertically downwards by the margin on the span.

Comment: as Alohci said they are not same if you remove the height from div and add display: flex; align-item: center; you will see span is not aligning with ancher tags.